# onblur is not working in chrome properly

Tags: javascript

I called `onblur` function in a text box using c# but it is not working properly in chrome.
I have apply this script to validate e-mail format in text box.

```
function ValidateEmail(uemail) {
    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if (uemail.value.match(mailformat)) {
        jQuery(uemail).css("border", "0px");
        return true;
    }

    if (uemail.value.trim() == "") {
        jQuery(uemail).css("border", "0px");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        //alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
        //uemail.focus();

        jQuery(uemail).css('cssText', 'border :1px solid red !important');
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in textbox control i call onblur function
"onblur='ValidateEmail(this)"

It is working fine in firefox but not in chrome.

Comment: What does it means it's not working in chrome properly ? What happens ?

Comment: This line doesn't make sense: `jQuery(uemail).css('cssText', 'border :1px solid red !important');`

Comment: How are you attaching that function to the element?

Comment: yes i called that script in text box Using this code"onblur='ValidateEmail(this)'
and this line
"jQuery(uemail).css('cssText', 'border :1px solid red !important');"
makes the border of the textbox red when we put wrong email on onblur function.

Comment: Please reproduce your problem in a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<a href="#" tabindex="0" onblur="alert('blur')"> blur me </a>
```

Check this out it is working here there may be some problem with your code